# How to get Config array parameters in controller to send it to twig for displaying it in form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form that has location field. Creating a `ChoiceType` class with dropdown and for options I have defined all the locations in config.yml as parameters.

config.yml:

```
parameters:
    locations:[location1, location2, location3]
```

Controller Form Field:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($abc)
    ->add('location', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Select Location', 
        'choices'=> $this->getParameter('locations'),
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

This is displaying array location i.e. `0` for location1, `1` for location2 etc, But I want to display array values.

Other things I tried, placing this parameters in a array and then trying `array_value` options. I got to display location by:

```
$arrayincontroller=$this->getParameter('locations')
```

and in form:

```
->add('location', ChoiceType:class, array('label' => 'Select Location', 'choices'=> array($arrayincontroller[0] => $arrayincontroller[0])
```

but don't want to write each and every location like this. Is there any better method to pass values to form. Tried to include foreach but guess I can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the parameters as array as follow:

```
parameters:
    locations:
        location1: location1
        location2: location2
        location3: location3
```

Retrieve always as:

```
$arrayincontroller=$this->getParameter('locations')
```

But use as follow:

```
->add('location', ChoiceType:class, array('label' => 'Select Location', 'choices'=> $arrayincontroller);
```

Hope this help

Comment: Is there any disadvantage of doing ->add('location', ChoiceType:class, array('label' => 'Select Location', 'choices'=> $this->getParameter('locations');

Comment: Hi @HarshulR yes no problem to do directly has you comment